# How to set Axis step range in Google Chart?

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

Hello All i want to create Google Chart but getting a problem like `ticks:` add as like `[0, -50000, -100000, -150000, -200000]` ... it's working fine but add only range as `500000` and set auto ticks... Thanks in advance.

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBackgroundColor);

function drawBackgroundColor() {
 
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      var amount_array = [];
      //data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
   data.addColumn('date', 'Product');
   data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');
  data.addRows([
     
   [ new Date(2015,4,20),-199525],
     
   [ new Date(2015,4,27),-195930],
     
   [ new Date(2015,5,17),-175720],
     
   [ new Date(2015,7,05),-189725],
     
   [ new Date(2015,8,11),-174875],
     
   [ new Date(2015,8,30),-170819],
     
   [ new Date(2015,9,07),-176488],
     
   [ new Date(2015,9,21),-188950],
     
   [ new Date(2015,9,28),-190418],
     
   [ new Date(2015,10,05),-183461],
     
   [ new Date(2015,10,12),-189215],
     
   [ new Date(2015,10,18),-192451],
     
   [ new Date(2015,10,26),-184334],
     
   [ new Date(2015,11,03),-191307],
     
   [ new Date(2015,11,09),-188478],
     
   [ new Date(2015,11,16),-194779],
     
   [ new Date(2016,0,06),-218751],
     
   [ new Date(2016,0,20),-226485],
     ]);
  
      amount_array[0] = '-199.5k';
        amount_array[1] = '-195.9k';
        amount_array[2] = '-175.7k';
        amount_array[3] = '-189.7k';
        amount_array[4] = '-174.8k';
        amount_array[5] = '-170.8k';
        amount_array[6] = '-176.4k';
        amount_array[7] = '-188.9k';
        amount_array[8] = '-190.4k';
        amount_array[9] = '-183.4k';
        amount_array[10] = '-189.2k';
        amount_array[11] = '-192.4k';
        amount_array[12] = '-184.3k';
        amount_array[13] = '-191.3k';
        amount_array[14] = '-188.4k';
        amount_array[15] = '-194.7k';
        amount_array[16] = '-218.7k';
        amount_array[17] = '-226.4k';
      
  // custom format data values
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
  data.setFormattedValue(i, 1, amount_array[i]);  
    }
  
  
 var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')); 
  

      var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: '',
    gridlineColor: '#fff',
    textPosition: 'none',
        },  
        vAxis: {
          title: '',    
    textStyle: {
     color: '#a7b3bc',     
     fontSize: 14,
     bold: true,     
   },
    ticks: [0, -50000, -100000, -150000, -200000],
        },
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
  series: {
         0: { color: '#5cbd60' }            
        },
  pointSize: 2,
  baselineColor: '#e6e6e6',
  legend: {position: 'none'},
  chartArea: {
   backgroundColor: {
          stroke: '#e6e6e6',
          strokeWidth: 1
      },
   width: 330,
   height: 155,
   top:20,
   bottom:20
  },
  width: 430,
  height : 200
 };
 
 
 
 // get the axis values and reformat them
    var runOnce = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        google.visualization.events.removeListener(runOnce);
        var bb, val, formattedVal, suffix, ticks = [], cli = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
  
  
  
        for (var i = 0; bb = cli.getBoundingBox('vAxis#0#gridline#' + i); i++) {
            val = cli.getVAxisValue(bb.top);
   
   
   
            if (val != parseInt(val)) {
                val = cli.getVAxisValue(bb.top + bb.height / 2);
            }            
            // convert from base-10 counting to 2^10 counting
            for (var n = 0; val >= 1000; n++) {   
                //val /= 1000;
    val = val / 1000;    
            }
   
   formattedVal = val;
            val *= Math.pow(1000, n);
            
     
            switch (n) {
                case 0:
                    suffix = '$-';
                    break;
                case 1:
                    suffix = 'K';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    suffix = 'M';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    suffix = 'G';
                    break;
     case 4:
                    suffix = 'T';
                    break;
                default:
                    while (n > 4) {
                        formattedVal *= 1000;
                        n--;
                    }
                    suffix = 'k'
            }
   
   
   if(formattedVal >= 1){
    ticks.push({v: val, f: Math.round(formattedVal) + suffix});
   }
   else if(formattedVal < 0){    
    var formattedVal1 = formattedVal / 1000;
    ticks.push({v: val, f: Math.round(formattedVal1) + 'K'});
   }
   else{
    ticks.push({v: val, f: suffix}); 
   }
            
        }
 
        options.vAxis = options.vAxis || {};
        options.vAxis.ticks = ticks;
        chart.draw(data, options);
  
    }); 
 
 chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate `ticks` by specifying min,max and interval parameters as demonstrated below:

```
function calcIntTicks(dataTable, options) {
    var min = options.hasOwnProperty("min")  ? options.min : Math.floor(dataTable.getColumnRange(1).min);
    var max = options.hasOwnProperty("max") ? options.max : Math.ceil(dataTable.getColumnRange(1).max);
    var vals = [];
    for (var cur = min; cur <= max; cur += options.interval) {
        vals.push(cur);
    }
    return vals;
}
```

**Modified example**

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart', 'line'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBackgroundColor);

function drawBackgroundColor() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var amount_array = [];
    //data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
    data.addColumn('date', 'Product');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');
    data.addRows([

        [new Date(2015, 4, 20), -199525],

        [new Date(2015, 4, 27), -195930],

        [new Date(2015, 5, 17), -175720],

        [new Date(2015, 7, 05), -189725],

        [new Date(2015, 8, 11), -174875],

        [new Date(2015, 8, 30), -170819],

        [new Date(2015, 9, 07), -176488],

        [new Date(2015, 9, 21), -188950],

        [new Date(2015, 9, 28), -190418],

        [new Date(2015, 10, 05), -183461],

        [new Date(2015, 10, 12), -189215],

        [new Date(2015, 10, 18), -192451],

        [new Date(2015, 10, 26), -184334],

        [new Date(2015, 11, 03), -191307],

        [new Date(2015, 11, 09), -188478],

        [new Date(2015, 11, 16), -194779],

        [new Date(2016, 0, 06), -218751],

        [new Date(2016, 0, 20), -226485],
    ]);

    amount_array[0] = '-199.5k';
    amount_array[1] = '-195.9k';
    amount_array[2] = '-175.7k';
    amount_array[3] = '-189.7k';
    amount_array[4] = '-174.8k';
    amount_array[5] = '-170.8k';
    amount_array[6] = '-176.4k';
    amount_array[7] = '-188.9k';
    amount_array[8] = '-190.4k';
    amount_array[9] = '-183.4k';
    amount_array[10] = '-189.2k';
    amount_array[11] = '-192.4k';
    amount_array[12] = '-184.3k';
    amount_array[13] = '-191.3k';
    amount_array[14] = '-188.4k';
    amount_array[15] = '-194.7k';
    amount_array[16] = '-218.7k';
    amount_array[17] = '-226.4k';

    // custom format data values
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows() ; i++) {
        data.setFormattedValue(i, 1, amount_array[i]);
    }


    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));


    var options = {
        hAxis: {
            title: '',
            gridlineColor: '#fff',
            textPosition: 'none',
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: '',
            textStyle: {
                color: '#a7b3bc',
                fontSize: 14,
                bold: true,
            },
            //ticks: [0, -50000, -100000, -150000, -200000],
            ticks: calcIntTicks(data, { min: -200000, max: 0, interval: 50000 })
        },
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        series: {
            0: { color: '#5cbd60' }
        },
        pointSize: 2,
        baselineColor: '#e6e6e6',
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        chartArea: {
            backgroundColor: {
                stroke: '#e6e6e6',
                strokeWidth: 1
            },
            width: 330,
            height: 155,
            top: 20,
            bottom: 20
        },
        width: 430,
        height: 200
    };



    // get the axis values and reformat them
    var runOnce = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        google.visualization.events.removeListener(runOnce);
        var bb, val, formattedVal, suffix, ticks = [], cli = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();



        for (var i = 0; bb = cli.getBoundingBox('vAxis#0#gridline#' + i) ; i++) {
            val = cli.getVAxisValue(bb.top);



            if (val != parseInt(val)) {
                val = cli.getVAxisValue(bb.top + bb.height / 2);
            }
            // convert from base-10 counting to 2^10 counting
            for (var n = 0; val >= 1000; n++) {
                //val /= 1000;
                val = val / 1000;
            }

            formattedVal = val;
            val *= Math.pow(1000, n);


            switch (n) {
                case 0:
                    suffix = '$-';
                    break;
                case 1:
                    suffix = 'K';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    suffix = 'M';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    suffix = 'G';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    suffix = 'T';
                    break;
                default:
                    while (n > 4) {
                        formattedVal *= 1000;
                        n--;
                    }
                    suffix = 'k'
            }


            if (formattedVal >= 1) {
                ticks.push({ v: val, f: Math.round(formattedVal) + suffix });
            }
            else if (formattedVal < 0) {
                var formattedVal1 = formattedVal / 1000;
                ticks.push({ v: val, f: Math.round(formattedVal1) + 'K' });
            }
            else {
                ticks.push({ v: val, f: suffix });
            }

        }

        options.vAxis = options.vAxis || {};
        options.vAxis.ticks = ticks;
        chart.draw(data, options);

    });

    chart.draw(data, options);
}



function calcIntTicks(dataTable, options) {
    var min = options.hasOwnProperty("min")  ? options.min : Math.floor(dataTable.getColumnRange(1).min);
    var max = options.hasOwnProperty("max") ? options.max : Math.ceil(dataTable.getColumnRange(1).max);
    var vals = [];
    for (var cur = min; cur <= max; cur += options.interval) {
        vals.push(cur);
    }
    return vals;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```